# Access a properties file within a dependency jar in a war tomcat via classpath Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

Let A be my core jar maven based project class. And W be my war in another project. I have added A as my dependency to  W. I have stored my prop.properties file in A in the resource folder. How do I access the properties file from the jar using *classpath* in my war. Using Spring 4.
I have updated spring.xml for the jar with the following:

```
 <context:property-placeholder 
 location="classpath:prop.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Asterisk](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards) after `classpath` this will tell spring to look for configuration in all the added dependencies in your classpath:

```
<context:property-placeholder 
 location="classpath*:prop.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```